# What is considered as noise if it comes to comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, noise-reduction

We've got the option to flag comments as "noise, offensive or spam", offensive and spam is pretty clear...but what is considered as noise?

I mean, sometimes people drift off into a discussion which is not directly related to the question (but my cover further raising questions to that topic), would that be noise? On the other hand I'm pretty sure that comments like "recompile the kernel" on Linux questions should be considered as noise, but should I also flag them?

Comment: Decided to delete my answer. After reading the comments and reflecting on what I wrote, I realised I was wrong.

Comment: fwiw, I agreed with you @chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are generally looser in what is acceptable than posts.

The general standard is "relevant to the post, poster, or the previous comments" For this reason, in comments, noise-flagging can be enacted almost literally: "blah blah blah" or "I like <strike>monkeys</strike> the monkees" would both be considered as noise because they *bear no relation to the post they are commenting on*.

Comment: Decided to delete my answer. After reading the comments and reflecting on what I wrote, I realised I was wrong.

Comment: @ChrisF : done.